# How to put a background image BEHIND a page container

Tags: html, css

I am managing my school's website (mpkosis28.com) with NO prior programming experiences. If any, I'm just a 15yo computer technician.

I made a subdomain: http://28cup.mpkosis.com/index.html (yes, I really need to learn php to get rid of html files. And some graphic designing as well.) and I need to put an image behind the content. Something like twitter's background which is shown around the twitter feed.

I can't copy my css code, because I am confused with the formatting here, [but here it is.](http://28cup.mpkosis28.com/css/style.css)

EDIT: putting a background on the white bars on the side. Like a floating page container with an image behind it.

Comment: Just make it the body background

Comment: Please review my answer as has been a while since it was posted

Comment: You will never get rid of HTML. Please copy the part of source code in your case css, which is essentiel for this question.

Comment: This question has been answered. And I'm aware that I can't get rid of HTML, although I am seeking to trim the files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably just need to add the image to the body tag, like this:

```
body {
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, Verdana, Sans-serif;
    font-size: 12px;
    color: #666666;
    background: url(path/to/image/file.jpg);
}
```

The white bars is just a default page background. Use the above code in your css and make the path correct and it will work

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but somehow it doesn't work. I used an arma 3 wallpaper to test, but the white bars are still visible. I added the above code to the **body** tag, not the **html, body** tag. Am I doing it wrong?

Comment: What is the path of your image?

Comment: If you post the path of your uploaded image (and upload updated css as i can see its still the old one) i can have a proper look :)

Comment: FIXED IT. Apparently I needed to write only one background so it looks like this:

{ background: url(../images/test/arma3.jpg) #ffffff; } . Thanks for the help!

Comment: Glad you fixed it :) Please accept my answer & up vote if it has helped :)

Comment: Can't, said that I have to have 15 reputations to vote up. Accepted your answer though.